# Calling of webservice in titanium mobile application code always return response with status code 0

Tags: rest, mobile, titanium, httpclient, titanium-mobile

I am new to titanium appcelerator family. Also I am not sure if somebody has posted the same problem before. I couldn't found it so posting it here.

I am developing one mobile application. And in my application I am trying to call one web service which is hosted on my local environment, but it is always returning response with status code 0 and error message "Can't reach host". So I thought that there should be some problem with my web service that I deployed on remote location. And hence I have tried to call some other web services like twitter, but it's same.. :( It is giving me an error while calling twitter web service also.

I also check for a cross domain policy issue. So I have also tried to set rule on server for web service, but it didn't work out. Following is code snippet and environment details that I am using.

1. **Application type:** Mobile
2. **Titanium SDK:** 2.1.4 GA
3. **Device:** Web Browser
4. **Host Operating System:** Windows 7
5. **Titanium Studio:** Titanium Studio, build: 2.1.2.201208301612

Files for sample web service which is I am calling is present on following locations:

1. **http://db.tt/XoSCujux** (api.php)
2. **http://db.tt/bJG2A5XT** (Rest.inc.php)
3. **http://db.tt/Hxt6Oojx** (.htaccess)

**Code:**

```
//declare the http client object
            var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

            //this method will process the remote data
            xhr.onload = function() { 
                //check to see if we are refreshing the data via our 
                //pull and release mechanism

                //create a json object using the JSON.PARSE function
                result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                Ti.API.info(result);
                console.log(result);

                var msgTitle = "data:";
                var msgText = result;
                var alertBox = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                            title: msgTitle,
                            message: msgText
                        });
                alertBox.show();    
            };  


            //this method will fire if there's an error in accessing the remote data
            xhr.onerror = function(e) {  
                //log the error to our titanium developer console 
                Ti.API.error(this.status + ' - ' + this.statusText);
                console.log(this.status + ' - ' + this.statusText); 



                var msgTitle = "Error : " + this.status;
                var msgText = "Error Text : " + this.statusText;
                var alertBox = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                            title: msgTitle,
                            message: msgText
                        });
                alertBox.show();    

                 Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
                    Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
                    Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
                    alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.' +  e.error);
            };  

            //open up the recipes xml feed
            xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1/rest_example/api.php?rquest=locations");

            //finally, execute the call to the remote feed
            xhr.send();
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This error code indicates that the response was empty, (check for headers?). Probably your local webserver is not setup correctly, or your not calling it right.

Comment: The problem is resolved when I am running app in android emulator and trying to make webservice call.